# PHP Variable in JavaScript Tag

Tags: javascript, php

I need a help with using PHP variable in JavaScript situation.
I want to use PHP variable in a morris chart such as,

```
var area = new Morris.Area({
                    element: 'revenue-chart',
                    resize: true,
                    data: [
                        {y: '6D', fab: 20004, qc: 0},
                        {y: '5D', fab: 2778, qc: 0},
                        {y: '4D', fab: 4912, qc: 0},
                        {y: '3D', fab: 3767, qc: 0},
                        {y: '2D', fab: 6810, qc: 0},
                        {y: '1D', fab: <?php echo $sumWeightYesterday; ?>, qc: 0},
                        {y: 'NOW', fab: 4820, qc: 0}
                    ],
                    parseTime: false,
                    xkey: 'y',
                    ykeys: ['fab', 'qc'],
                    labels: ['FAB', 'QC'],
                    lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
                    hideHover: 'auto'
                });
```

I want to use `$sumWeightYesterday` but it displays `0` on the data.

Please help me,
Thanks

Comment: Looks correct. If this is in an external JS file, it has to be .php too and served with appropriate mime headers

Comment: What does the **generated** code look like? I.e. the code the browser evaluates?

Comment: Assuming this file is executed by PHP and assuming that `$sumWeightYesterday` actually has a value (not `0`), you should always use `json_encode()` when injecting into JavaScript. For example `fab: <?= json_encode($sumWeightYesterday) ?>`

Comment: @Phil, didn't know about "always should use `json_encode()`" — any reason for that?

Comment: @l'L'l it just sanitises your variable for use in JavaScript. For example, strings will be quoted correctly without having to worry about escaping single / double quotes, etc.

Comment: @Phil good suggestion phil, no i figured it out

Comment: @marmar and the problem was... ?

Comment: Fab seems to be numeric. If so, no need to json_encode it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it.

```
var sumWeightYesterday = <?php echo $sumWeightYesterday; ?>

var area = new Morris.Area({
                    element: 'revenue-chart',
                    resize: true,
                    data: [
                        {y: '6D', fab: 20004, qc: 0},
                        {y: '5D', fab: 2778, qc: 0},
                        {y: '4D', fab: 4912, qc: 0},
                        {y: '3D', fab: 3767, qc: 0},
                        {y: '2D', fab: 6810, qc: 0},
                        {y: '1D', fab: sumWeightYesterday, qc: 0},
                        {y: 'NOW', fab: 4820, qc: 0}
                    ],
                    parseTime: false,
                    xkey: 'y',
                    ykeys: ['fab', 'qc'],
                    labels: ['FAB', 'QC'],
                    lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
                    hideHover: 'auto'
                });
```